R MSM package: how to flag incident and prevalent disease?
I am trying to create a 2-state Markov model (state 1 to 2 and 2 to 1) with the msm package in R. hpv_state is 2 when infected, 1 when not infected, and 999 when status is unknown. I would like to create a variable to flag whether each infection episode is prevalent (continuously 2 from the start of follow-up) or incident (2 after a 1 has been observed). When I leave infection_type missing when hpv_state=1, the model seems to ignore those entries. How should I properly flag the infection_type when hpv_state=1 or 999?
The purpose of the infection_type variable would be for 2 to 1 transition only:
hpv16_inft.msm <- msm(hpv_state ~ years_followup, subject=patientid, data=df_hpv16, qmatrix=Q, censor=999, covariates = list("2-1" = ~infection_type))

Example of the data:
   patientid hpv_state infection_type                
10 1-0002            2 Prevalent     
11 1-0002            1 NA            
12 1-0002            2 Incident      
13 1-0002            2 Incident      
14 1-0002          999 NA            
15 1-0002          999 NA            
16 1-0002            1 NA            

I tried assigning a value to NA(i.e., "neg"), but it is not logical to have a transition from infection_type=neg to hpv_state=1.

So, I redesigned the model to be a 3-state model instead, and it works fine.
Prevalence -> Negative <=> Incidence

